# Possible to use logic statement directly in UserForm.AddItem?

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, userform

I know and understand the usual method of adding items to a `ListBox` using a logical test:

```
If a = 1 Then
    ListBox1.AddItem x
End If
```

However, I was wondering if it is at all possible to `.AddItem` directly with a logic statement? Something like:

```
ListBox1.AddItem If a = 1
```

This is not a burning question that has me stumped. I just want to know if there is an alternative method to add to my knowledge base.

Comment: no it isn't possible with VBA

Comment: What's the difference between these one-liners: `listbox1.addItem If a = 1` vs `If a = 1 then listbox1.addItem` Why not just use the latter?

Comment: The second part (if a = 1) is the logic statement that I was hoping could be clarified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware you cannot add logic statment directly with .addItem method. However, you can define a function, for example:

```
Function check(b As Integer)

    If b = 1 Then

        check = "x"

    Else

    End If

End Function
```

And then use .addItem like:

```
ListBox1.AddItem check(a)
```

Edit: As @robinCTS noticed unfortunatelly this method will result on adding blank item do listbox item. So it would only work if you would like to have an alternative (for example add "x" or "y" depending on condition). It appears that issue with blank row could be only solved by removing it after .addItem line.

Comment: Great answers. Exactly what I've been looking for

Comment: @gavin Unfortunately, this answer doesn't quite work as might be expected. If `a = 1` then an `x` item is added to the end of the ListBox. However, if `a <> 1` then it is **not** the case that no item is added. A "blank" item is actually appended.

Comment: @robinCTS is right, this would only work if you would like to have non-empty alternative...

Answer (score 2):

If the logic statement is required to determine whether or not to add the item, then the answer is: no<sup>*</sup> it is not possible. As soon as the `.AddItem` method is called, **an item will be added**. If no parameters are supplied (or the parameter is `Null`/`Empty`/`vbNullString`/certain non-printable characters), a blank item is appended to the end.

The only one-line solution is to do what K.Dᴀᴠɪs suggested:

```
If a = 1 Then ListBox1.AddItem x
```

---

If, however, the logic statement is there to choose between different items to be added, then yes, it is possible.

**Method 1** - `IIf()` (inline if):

```
ListBox1.AddItem IIf(a = 1, x, y)
```

where `a = 1` ~> `ListBox1.AddItem x`, otherwise ~> `ListBox1.AddItem y`.

**Method 2** - `Choose()`:

```
ListBox1.AddItem Choose(a, x, y, z)
```

where `a = 1` ~> `ListBox1.AddItem x`, `a = 2` ~> `ListBox1.AddItem y`, `a = 3` ~> `ListBox1.AddItem z`, etc.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> Technically speaking, it *is* possible. However, it requires error trapping and a slightly convoluted use of the `.AddItem` method's second parameter<sup>**</sup>:</sub>

```
On Error Resume Next
ListBox1.AddItem x, IIf(a = 1, ListBox1.ListCount, -2)
On Error GoTo 0
```

<sub>The `-2` insertion index forces an error if the condition fails, whilst the `ListBox1.ListCount` index causes the item to be appended to the end of the list. The `On Error` statements cause the `.AddItem` method to be skipped when the error occurs.</sub>

<sub>The second parameter can also be rewritten in a few different ways, e.g.:</sub>

```
ListBox1.AddItem x, ListBox1.ListCount + IIf(a = 1, 0, 1)
ListBox1.AddItem x, ListBox1.ListCount + (a = 1) + 1
```

<sub><sup>**</sup> It is also possible to have a logic statement *without* using the second parameter, but it either requires differentiation between strings and numbers or always casting to a string, and the results are not as easy to read/understand:</sub>

```
On Error Resume Next
' for numbers
ListBox1.AddItem 42 / -(a = 1)
' or for strings
ListBox1.AddItem "42" & String$(0 / (a = 1), 0)
' or for both
ListBox1.AddItem CStr(x) & String$(0 / (a = 1), 0)
ListBox1.AddItem CStr(x) & Choose(1 / (a = 1))
ListBox1.AddItem CStr(x) & IIf(1 / (a = 1), "", "")
On Error GoTo 0
```

<sub>The trick this time is to force a divide-by-zero error when the condition fails, and otherwise either dividing numbers by 1 or appending a null string to strings. ( `String$(0, 0)` returns a null string, and `Choose(-1)` returns `Null`, which concatenates like a null string.)</sub>

<sub>**Notes:**</sub>

- <sup>While all these examples append the item to the end of the list, they *can* be modified to prepend or insert in the middle.</sup>
- <sup>In general, using the `On Error` statements this way is **not** recommended. A proper error handler that checks for, and only resumes on, the specific appropriate error should <s>almost always</s> **always** be used. (With all other trapped errors re-raised, of course.)</sup>

Comment: That is amazing. Thank you muchly

Comment: @gavin Don't forget to "accept" the best correct answer to your questions by clicking on the grey tick at the top left of the answer ;-)

Comment: @gavin No problemo.

Comment: Great answer. Very interesting use of IIf.

Comment: @TomJohnRiddle Thanks. (And for the upvote ;-) ) Yeah, once you learn about `IIf()` and start to use it, you can do a lot of nifty things. You just have to be careful because there is no short-circuiting - all three parts are always executed.